# State of repeater is not persisted after postback when inside a panel

Tags: asp.net, user-controls, postback, repeater, viewstate

I have following code structure in markup :

```
        <asp:Panel ID="Panel1" runat="server" Title="TestPanel" Visible="true">
          <asp:GridView ID="grd1" runat="server" AutoGenerateColumns="true">        
          </asp:GridView>
          <myControl:RepeaterUserControl ID="rpt"></myControl:RepeaterUserControl>
        </asp:Panel>
```

The panel is used to control visibilty (currently set true for all time). The control 'RepeaterUserControl' is a user control which contains a asp repeater with two buttons named 'Ok' and 'Cancel' (all initially set display:none). All this content of user control is shown on page as modal popup (using modal popup extender) on click of a 'Invoke' button which is also a part of the user control.

```
<div id="div1" runat="server">
    <ajax:ModalPopupExtender ID="ModalPopupExtender1" runat="server" PopupControlID="divDialog"
        TargetControlID="btnDummyInvoker" CancelControlID="imbClose" PopupDragHandleControlID="divDialogTitle"
        BackgroundCssClass="modalBackground">
    </ajax:ModalPopupExtender>
    <div style="height: 4px;">
    </div>
    <asp:Button ID="btnInvoke" runat="server" OnClick="btnInvoke_Click" Text="Invoke"
        Width="90px" />
    <div style="display: none; position: absolute;">
        <asp:Button ID="Button2" runat="server" />
    </div>
    <div id="div2" runat="server" style="display: none;">
        <asp:Repeater ID="rptList" runat="server">
            <ItemTemplate>
                <tr>
                    <td>
                        <asp:Label ID="lblName" runat="server" Text='<%# Eval("DisplayText").ToString() %>'></asp:Label>
                    </td>
                </tr>
            </ItemTemplate>
        </asp:Repeater>
        <asp:Button ID="btnOk" runat="server" OnClick="btnOk_Click" />
        <asp:Button ID="btnCancel" runat="server" />
    </div>
</div>
```

So below the grid, user sees a button (Invoke) on page, on click of which the repeater control and the Ok/Cancel buttons are shown in the modal popup. The repeater is assigned a datasource which contains the list of items, user makes changes and on the ok click of the popup, from code behind (ok OnClick event) I access repeater as rptList.Items.Count to do further operations.

**Now the problem.**
If the user control is outside the panel it perfectly returns me the correct count of items, but if the userControl in inside the panel (as shown in code) the count returned on click of ok button is '0' after postback. 
why is the repeater losing its state in this case ?

**Update :** Adding code snippet from code-behind, if it helps solving the issue

```
//This is from the user control code
 protected void btnInvoke_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
        {   
          rptList.DataSource = listToBeBoundToRepeater;
          rptList.DataBind();
          modalPopupExtender.Show();             
        }

//This is from the user control code
 protected void btnOk_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
        {

            for (int itemIndex = 0; itemIndex < rptList.Items.Count; itemIndex++)
            {
               // business logiv
            }

        }
```

rptList.Items.Count is 0 for me after postback for the case I described.

**update2 :** 
Here is the weird solution I got, I enclosed the grid and repeater with a  tag and set the runat property to server to make it a server control. Now its persisting the values of the repeater after postback properly. Strange, but working now.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Here is the weird solution I got, I enclosed the grid and repeater with a  tag and set the runat property to server to make it a server control. Now its persisting the values of the repeater after postback properly. Strange, but working now.

Comment: I've tried about 10 different solutions and this combined with always data binding instead of not doing it on postback fixed the issue for me.

Answer (score 0):

for `<asp:UpdatePanel ID="UpdatePanel1" runat="server">`, define AsyncPostbackTrigger as btnInvoke

Comment: Hi, Ignore the update panel. the problem is still there without it.

Answer (score 0):

Edit: Removed previous answer.
I tried simulating your problem as much as possible in using a main panel containing a usercontrol which contains a repeater that is shown with the ajaxcontroltoolkit.
Alas my repeater item count is always correct though.
Container page :

```
<%@ Register TagPrefix="a" TagName="test" Src="cc.ascx" %>

<asp:Content ID="BodyContent" runat="server" ContentPlaceHolderID="MainContent">
<asp:ScriptManager ID="ScriptManager1" runat="server" />   
    <asp:Panel ID="Panel1" runat="server" Title="TestPanel" Visible="true">
        <a:test runat="server" ID="test"></a:test>
    </asp:Panel>
</asp:Content>
```

user control cc aspx :

```
<%@ Register TagPrefix="ajax" Namespace="AjaxControlToolkit" Assembly="AjaxControlToolkit, Version=4.1.60501.0, Culture=neutral, PublicKeyToken=28f01b0e84b6d53e" %>

<div id="div1" runat="server">
    <ajax:ModalPopupExtender ID="ModalPopupExtender1" runat="server" PopupControlID="divDialog"
        TargetControlID="btnDummyInvoker"
        BackgroundCssClass="modalBackground">
    </ajax:ModalPopupExtender>
    <asp:Button runat="server" style="display:none" ID="btnDummyInvoker"/>
    <div style="height: 4px;">
    </div>
    <asp:Button ID="btnInvoke" runat="server" OnClick="btnInvoke_Click" Text="Invoke" Width="90px" />
    <div style="display: none; position: absolute;">
        <asp:Button ID="Button2" runat="server" />
    </div>
    <div id="divDialog" runat="server" style="display: none;">
        <asp:Repeater ID="rptList" runat="server">
            <ItemTemplate>
                <tr>
                    <td>
                        <asp:Label ID="lblName" runat="server" Text='<%# Eval("DisplayText").ToString() %>'></asp:Label>
                    </td>
                </tr>
            </ItemTemplate>
        </asp:Repeater>
        <asp:Button ID="btnOk" runat="server" OnClick="btnOk_Click" />
        <asp:Button ID="btnCancel" runat="server" />
    </div>
    <asp:TextBox runat="server" ID="result"></asp:TextBox>
</div>
```

user control code behind :

```
public partial class cc : System.Web.UI.UserControl
    {
        protected void Page_Load(object sender, EventArgs e)
        {

        }

        protected void btnInvoke_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
        {
            var list = new List<Data>();
            list.Add(new Data { DisplayText = "one" });
            list.Add(new Data { DisplayText = "two" });
            rptList.DataSource = list;
            rptList.DataBind();
            ModalPopupExtender1.Show();
        }

        protected void btnOk_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
        {
            var count = rptList.Items.Count;
            result.Text = count.ToString();
        }
    }
```

Comment: Hi, please ignore the update panel. the problem is still there without it. I have removed it from the code snipped from the main post.

Comment: my bad, seeing an update panel usually raises a red flag especially if the data doesnt seem transferred. Could you perhaps show a bit more code from your codebehind? I'm intrested in seeing how and when you exaclty bind your datasource(page_load,page_init) and how and when you do the count. Could you provide some snippets for that as well?

Comment: Also : just to get all the stupid possibilities out of the way. Could you rename Panel1 to something else without the word panel in it? I have had a single case in which this was the result of an error i received.

Comment: Hi, Thanks for the help. I have update the post with the codebehind code. Also the name is panel only in this example, in my code the name is something else. :)

Comment: I'm trying to reproduce your problem but i'm unsuccessfull so far. Maybe you could work towards me in simplifying this problem. Could you try elliminating the custom user control and letting me know if the problem is resolved like that?

Comment: i cant remove the custom control as it contains logic important to page, also I have used same control in 20 other places and it works fine everywhere else. I know the problem is weird and hard to explain :(

Comment: I will implement the custom control and if my solution still stands i will post it here. You can then either comment on where i did something other then you or compare with your imlementation to see the differences.

Comment: Here is the weird solution I got, I enclosed the grid and repeater with a <div> tag and set the runat property to server to make it a server control. Now its persisting the values of the repeater after postback properly. Strange, but working now.